# ASP.NET MVC 5 One-to-Many Relation with DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement a dropdown list, selecting items through a one-to-many relation.

When the form is POSTed back to the controller, the `package.Platform` object is null, so I'm somehow screwing up the mapping.

**/Models/Package.cs**

```
public class Package 
{
    public int ID {get; set;}

    ...

    public Platform Platform {get; set;}
}
```

**/Models/Platform.cs**

```
public class Platform
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

**/Controllers/PackagesController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(
    [Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Description,Version,Filename,Platform,IsPublished,ReleaseNotesURL")] Package package)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        package.Version = VersionParser.ParseVersion(package.Filename).ToString();
        db.Entry(package).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    PopulatePlatformsDropDownList(package.Platform.ID); //<<-- package.Platform is null

    return View(package);
}

...

private void PopulatePlatformsDropDownList(int? selectedPlatform)
{
    var platforms = from d in db.Platforms
                    orderby d.Name
                    select d;
    ViewBag.Platforms = new SelectList(platforms, "ID", "Name", selectedPlatform);
}
```

**/Views/Packages/Edit.cshtml**

```
...
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Platform, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Platform, (SelectList)ViewBag.Platforms)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Platform, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Which emits this HTML:

```
<select id="Platform" name="Platform" class="valid">
    <option value="1">Option One</option>
    <option value="2">Option Two</option>
</select>
```

The relation is persisted in SQL as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Packages](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    ...
    [Customer_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Platform_ID] [int] NULL
...

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Platforms](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
```

(omitted the FKs for brevity)

So, I need to get the `package.Platform` value to POST properly, grab it in the `Edit()` method of `PackagesController`, and save it away.

Comment: Your trying to bind you dropdown to a complex property. You can only bind to a value type. It would need to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => model.Platform.ID, ...` Currently when you post back, the `DefaultModelBinder` will try to set `package.Platform  = "1"` (or "2") which fails so the value of `Platform` is `null`

Comment: Note also `ModelState` will always be invalid because you have a `[Required]` attribute on `Platform.Name` property (you not binding to the `Name` property so it will always be `null` and therefore invalid)

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's great! I'm now getting the Package.Platform object in my POST action. However, it's not saving to the database on SaveChanges(). Here's the generated SQL: UPDATE [dbo].[Packages]
SET [Name] = @0, [Description] = @1, [Version] = @2, [Filename] = @3, [IsPublished] = @4, [ReleaseNotesURL] = @5
WHERE ([ID] = @6) -- Note Platform_ID is missing.

Comment: I don't use EF so cant be sure, but I suspect `Package` needs to include the foreign key/navigation property - `public int Platform_ID { get; set; } public virtual Platform Platform { get; set; }` - and you bind the dropdown to  `Platform_ID`

Comment: I think the navigation property is supposed to be implicit, but I'll give it a shot.